# Apple Magic Trackpad aftrer upgrade from Ubuntu 11.10 to Ubuntu 12.04 (64 Bit) - Multitouch not working!

Tags: 12.04, multi-touch, apple, trackpad

The title describes my problem. On Ubuntu 11.10 Multi-touch worked fine on my Apple Magic Trackpad. Now i have only "ONE-FINGER-Control". Scrolling is only possible on the right side of the pad with one finger. Three or four fingers are also not working any more (four fingers to to get the Dash or three fingers to move a window).
What could I do to get this working again?? (on 12.04)

Comment: Have you tried re-installing all of your drivers yet?

Comment: no, i didn't install any driver on 11.10. I don't know what to re-install. I only did the pairing by "Using the Commandline" (from https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Multitouch/AppleMagicTrackpad) because there exists a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bluez/+bug/618838

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get this working I had to install utouch:

```
apt-get install utouch
```

For details, read:

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Multitouch
- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Multitouch/Architecture
- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Multitouch/AppleMagicTrackpad

Comment: THX! It works now for 3 and 4 fingers. The only thing that does not work is two finger scrolling. On the mouse settings I can't set 2 finger scrolling, because my notebooks touchpad does not support 2 finger scrolling. So this option is disabled. Any ideas to get this separately (touchpad for notebook with sidescrolling and apple magic trackpad with 2 finger scrolling) working??

Comment: That ubuntu wiki page does not at this moment exist...

Answer (score 1):

I was able to enable two-finger scroll by using the xinput command. xinput with no arguments shows all the input devices on the system. The Apple Trackpad was device 9 in my list; I used command xinput list-props 9 to see all the properties for the Apple Trackpad. I then disabled the edge scroll using the Mouse and Touchpad menu in System Settings, then enabled two-finger scrolling (282) using xinput.

xinput set-prop 9 282 1 1

The change is NOT reflected in the System Settings --> Mouse and Touchpad settings, but everything now works.