# Enabling Multi-touch features of the Apple Magic Mouse on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: application-development, mouse, multi-touch, magic-mouse, magic-trackpad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Apple Magic Trackpad aftrer upgrade from Ubuntu 11.10 to Ubuntu 12.04 (64 Bit) - Multitouch not working!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133970/apple-magic-trackpad-aftrer-upgrade-from-ubuntu-11-10-to-ubuntu-12-04-64-bit)

I want to write a simple app that uses Apple's Magic Trackpad, nothing special, just so that it recognizes atleast one gesture. The thing is, Ubuntu itself doesnt really recognize this device.
I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and by default the device works with 1 finger, but without tap-click or doubletap, 3 fingers move the window and 3 finger spread makes it fullscreen. I managed to enable 2 finger scrolling with "xinput set-prop 8 'Two-Finger Scrolling' 1 1", but thats about it. No other gestures work, ginn doesnt start, giesview detects the device but doesnt respond to any of the gestures, and touchegg doesnt start either.
I tried example apps from qt that come with ubuntu but they dont work.

So... what do i do? i tried using qt but all i get from the app is "Got touch without getting TouchBegin for id XX"
what else can i use to get my app to work with multitouch devices?

Comment: I've changed the title since the problem isn't about developing multi-touch enabled app, but getting the multi-touch features of the Magic Mouse working on 12.04. Once you have that, you should be OK to go from there.